# How to initialize react state without causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const [dataIn, setDataIn] = useState<skillData[] | any>([]);

console.log("event loop");  
if(dataIn.length === 0) {
    console.log("updating data");
    const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
    const tempData : any = [];
    const data = await getDocs(collection(db, "MainWebsiteSkillsData"))
    data.forEach(elm => {
        tempData.push({...elm.data(), key : elm.id});
    });
    setDataIn(tempData);
} else {
    console.log("data already updated");
}
```

So, I'm trying to get some data from firestore and convert it to an array and save that to the state but all implementations lead to different issues.

Directly adding it in like this causes an infinite loop and adding it inside a useEffect block does not update the state.

Either ways, is there any way to do this that does not cause an infinite loop? Why does the state not get updated? I read something about the closures not being the same on each re-render but I am using a const variable to make sure it persists. I'm even using a temporary variable as suggested by other threads but the state still isn't being updated.

Comment: Is your async code in a `useEffect` hook?

Comment: No, I don't think useEffect can be async, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a firebaseApp.ts to store all initial data.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp(); //prevent initializeApp() from being called multiple times
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, firestore, auth, storage };
```

I would not use any type.

```
const [dataIn, setDataIn] = useState<skillData[] | null>([]);
```

Fetch data

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const docRef = collection(firestore, "MainWebsiteSkillsData");
    const q = query(
      docRef,
      where("type", "==", "apple"),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      limit(10)
    ); //you can set some options here
    //if no options, just replace the q to docRef
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const rawDocData = doc.data();
        //I prefer to create a zod.js object for checking valid data
        const docData = zodSchema.safeParse(rawDocData);
        if (docData.success) {
          return {...docData.data, key: doc.id} //add key value
        }
      });
      const finalProduct = data.flatMap((f) => (f ? [f] : [])); //remove undefined
      setDataIn(finalProduct)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error)
    }
    return null
  }

  fetchData()
}, []);
```